# Chrome Extension run for a specific script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying modify the following code to show the icon when a website contains an specific .js from an 3rd website.

How i must edit the "matches"?

I have the following code but its showing always the same icon.

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["content.js", "jquery-3.4.1.min.js"],
      "css": ["content.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The fragment of manifest.json doesn't seem related to the task you want to achieve. First you need to show the code and conditions that control that icon. Then clarify what you mean by "website contains an specific .js".

Comment: The website contains this code <script async src="//go.website.com/delivery/js/ex.js"></script>. How must modify the content_scripts for any website that contains the above script?

Comment: No need to modify manifest.json. You need to modify content.js and add a check for example like document.querySelector('script[src$="/ex.js"]'). Can't help further since you didn't provide more details.